# Computed properties on collection objects not updating when updating from server

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model (Form) that has a collection (Reasons) on it. I want to be able to save each of these reasons independently of each other.

I have a computed property (NeedsSaving) on the javascript object. I use this property to have the UI for each item in the collection flip between a save button or a complete button.

That works fine on initial page load, but once I make changes to the text and click Save, which reloads the item from the server, the NeedsSaving property doesn't update and says it still is in a changed state, and the save button will then stay shown when it should flip back to the complete button.

Reason form:

```
var reasonForm = function(data, parent) {
  let self = this;
  self.parent = parent;

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, reasonFormMapping, self);

  self.Reasons = ko.observableArray();

  self.saveReason = function (reason) {
    .ajax({
    // omitted
    }).done(function (response) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(response.data, {}, reason);
    })
    // omitted

  };
}
```

Reason:

```
var reason = function(data) {
  let self = this;
  let originalReason = data.Reason;

  self.Reason = ko.observable();
  self.IsComplete = ko.observable(false);
  self.NeedsSaving = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Reason() != originalReason;
  });

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

Sample of response from server

```
{
  "success":true,
  "message":"Reason #4 changes saved.",
  "data": {
    "Number":4,
    "Reason":"asdfasdfasdf",
    "IsComplete":false
  }
}
```

The first time I click save, it correctly saves the data to the db, but after the first click it doesn't work anymore. I'm not sure if I'm mapping incorrectly or what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
So I changed the .done function of the ajax call to the following:

```
var model = new reason(response.data);
ko.mapping.fromJS(model, {}, reason);
```

The first line is ok, all the properties are still observables. But after mapping with the second line, the NeedsSaving property has been changed to a regular boolean property instead of an observable. That's causing the UI to be wrong, but why is doing that?

Comment: If you add a `debugger;` in the `self.NeedsSaving` computed, does it get triggered after the response arrives?

Comment: It doesn't trigger.

Comment: I think a bit more detail might help... like, where does `saveReason` sit and what is the shape of the response?

Comment: See edits. Added server response and moved the saveReason to where it actually is (on reasonForm object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are only setting `originalReason` once, so after the first save your computed will always return true.

A quick fix is to make `originalReason` available on the `reason` objects and then set `originalReason` manually in your response handler.

Here's a cut-down [codepen](https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/QrQqQg)

A better way to approach this sort of problem would be (imo) to implement a dirty flag like [this example](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)

Comment: I thought the mapping plugin created a new object using the create part of the mapping, but it must just map values to properties on an existing object instead. Now it makes sense why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it updates when you hand it an existing model.